# (AngularJS) dynamically set CSS class by databinding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I notices that when I mix `ng-class` with `class + expression (class="something-{{ stuff }}")` which might not be set, the `ng-class` is not getting compiled.

Example:

This will work OK ([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kaxbg053/3/))

```
<div 
     ng-controller="MainCtrl" 
     ng-class="(data.size > 10) ? 'font-large' : 'font-small'"
     >
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

But when I use ng-class & class with expression **(which does not exist on the scope)** it will not work, it will not run/compile `ng-class`. ([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/seefeld/4z4s4hhs/5/)):

```
<div
    ng-controller="MainCtrl"
    class="just-a-class color-{{ data.color }}"
    ng-class="(data.size > 10) ? 'font-large' : 'font-small'"
    >
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

Is there any way to use both `ng-class` and `class with expression` or what is the workaround? Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: the second jsfiddle works, what am I missing here?

Comment: Your second jsfiddle works fine for me. The divs classes in Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit): `just-a-class color-red font-small`

Comment: I've done tidy-up and looks like is working OK now, I try to reproduce one more time.

Comment: Another way http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/647792as/ just modified your second working fiddle

Comment: @kasoban I was able to reproduce, the issues is visible when I try to bind something that does not exist on the scope, see fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to add a class with data binding or condition, use ng-class.

from angularjs's ng-class [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

This version is working well ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaxbg053/5/))

It uses only ng-class, with out the regular class

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" 
    ng-class="{'font-large' : (data.size >= 10), 
                'font-small' : (data.size < 10),
                'color-{{ data.nothing }}' : color.nothing }">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

this way ng-class will process the 'color-{{data.nothing}}' **only** if data.nothing is `true`

Comment: I think the issues is that ng-class is not getting compiled when the `data.nothing` does not exist. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9109

Comment: very nice example, I might move all of my class expression to the `ng-class` . What is best practice here?

Comment: yes, ng-class is designed for that. please accept answer if it helped.